# Modificar una celda y guardar su modificacion desde un DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagrid

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación para el control de etiquetas para la empresa donde trabajo. Estoy trabajando con un DataGridView el cual almacena los datos introducidos de los primeros Textbox como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento que inicia la aplicación el DataGridView permanece bloqueado hasta que se presiona el botón "editar". Lo que pretendo hacer es modificar una celda cual sea del DataGridView y al presionar el botón "Guardar" quede actualizada y así mismo los cambios en los textbox tanto de "Total" como de "Dividido entre 5" de igual manera se actualicen haciendo su respectiva función.

Al presionar el botón "insertar" este tiene la función de insertar los registros dentro del DataGridView, calcular la suma de cada columna con los registros contenidos y así mismo el total dividirlo entre 5.

Intente meter en el botón "Guardar" las mismas funciones que tengo para hacer el total y la división entre 5, pero creo que al cambiar un elemento desde el DataGridView no respeta el cambio que se hizo en la celda.

Anexo el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Etiquetado
{
    public partial class BotonNino : UserControl
    {
        public BotonNino()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;

        }

        private void BotonNino_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox1, "Editar");
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox2, "Guardar");

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna1.HeaderText = "17";
            Columna1.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna2.HeaderText = "17.5";
            Columna2.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna3.HeaderText = "18";
            Columna3.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna4.HeaderText = "18.5";
            Columna4.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna5.HeaderText = "19";
            Columna5.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna6 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna6.HeaderText = "19.5";
            Columna6.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna7 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna7.HeaderText = "20";
            Columna7.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna8 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna8.HeaderText = "20.5";
            Columna8.Width = 50;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Columna9 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            Columna9.HeaderText = "21";
            Columna9.Width = 50;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna1);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna2);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna3);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna4);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna5);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna6);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna7);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna8);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Columna9);

            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");

            //dt.Columns.Add("Apellido");

            //this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        }


            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "" || textBox5.Text == "" || textBox6.Text == "" || textBox7.Text == "" || textBox8.Text == "" || textBox9.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debes de ingresar todos los campos.");
            }
            else
            {

                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                int filas = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
                this.dataGridView1[0, filas].Value = textBox1.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[1, filas].Value = textBox2.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[2, filas].Value = textBox3.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[3, filas].Value = textBox4.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[4, filas].Value = textBox5.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[5, filas].Value = textBox6.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[6, filas].Value = textBox7.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[7, filas].Value = textBox8.Text;
                this.dataGridView1[8, filas].Value = textBox9.Text;




            }

            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
            textBox7.Clear();
            textBox8.Clear();
            textBox9.Clear();
        }


        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Ahora puedes editar la tabla");
            dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


    }

        private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (botonGuardar == true) { 
                for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; numColumna++)
                {
                    var sumTotal = 0;
                    var sumTotal1 = 0;
                    var sumTotal2 = 0;
                    var sumTotal3 = 0;
                    var sumTotal4 = 0;
                    var sumTotal5 = 0;
                    var sumTotal6 = 0;
                    var sumTotal7 = 0;
                    var sumTotal8 = 0;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {

                        sumTotal += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                        sumTotal1 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
                        sumTotal2 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                        sumTotal3 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
                        sumTotal4 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
                        sumTotal5 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);
                        sumTotal6 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value);
                        sumTotal7 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value);
                        sumTotal8 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Value);

                    }

                    textBox18.Text = sumTotal.ToString();//Aqui en cada iteración del for deberia ser el textbox correspondiente
                    textBox17.Text = sumTotal1.ToString();
                    textBox16.Text = sumTotal2.ToString();
                    textBox15.Text = sumTotal3.ToString();
                    textBox14.Text = sumTotal4.ToString();
                    textBox13.Text = sumTotal5.ToString();
                    textBox12.Text = sumTotal6.ToString();
                    textBox11.Text = sumTotal7.ToString();
                    textBox10.Text = sumTotal8.ToString();


                }

                textBox19.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
                textBox20.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox21.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox22.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox15.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox23.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox14.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox24.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox25.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox26.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();
                textBox27.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(5)).ToString();

            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado, saludos.

Gracias.

Comment: Broher, te recomiendo que pongas el codigo que llevas, ya que las ideas en el aire son dificiles de expresar y es mas facil detectar el problema y te daremos una solucion acorde a tu logica o tu codigo

Comment: Buen @srJJ listo anexe el código, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente logre hacerlo de esta forma:

1.Cree un evento CellClick el cual al hacer clic en alguna de las celdas a modificar muestra esa fila entero dentro de los textbox.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();


        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Al presionar el botón "guardar", el DataGriedView queda actualizado y realiza las funciones de calculo de "total" y "Dividido entre 5".

private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int poc;
        poc = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

        dataGridView1[0,poc].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1[1, poc].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1[2, poc].Value = textBox3.Text;
        dataGridView1[3, poc].Value = textBox4.Text;
        dataGridView1[4, poc].Value = textBox5.Text;
        dataGridView1[5, poc].Value = textBox6.Text;
        dataGridView1[6, poc].Value = textBox7.Text;
        dataGridView1[7, poc].Value = textBox8.Text;
        dataGridView1[8, poc].Value = textBox9.Text;

        for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; numColumna++)
        {
            var sumTotal = 0;
            var sumTotal1 = 0;
            var sumTotal2 = 0;
            var sumTotal3 = 0;
            var sumTotal4 = 0;
            var sumTotal5 = 0;
            var sumTotal6 = 0;
            var sumTotal7 = 0;
            var sumTotal8 = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                sumTotal += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                sumTotal1 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
                sumTotal2 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                sumTotal3 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
                sumTotal4 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
                sumTotal5 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);
                sumTotal6 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value);
                sumTotal7 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value);
                sumTotal8 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Value);

            }

            textBox18.Text = sumTotal.ToString();//Aqui en cada iteración del for deberia ser el textbox correspondiente
            textBox17.Text = sumTotal1.ToString();
            textBox16.Text = sumTotal2.ToString();
            textBox15.Text = sumTotal3.ToString();
            textBox14.Text = sumTotal4.ToString();
            textBox13.Text = sumTotal5.ToString();
            textBox12.Text = sumTotal6.ToString();
            textBox11.Text = sumTotal7.ToString();
            textBox10.Text = sumTotal8.ToString();


        }

        textBox19.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox20.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox17.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox21.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox22.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox23.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox24.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox25.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox26.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();
        textBox27.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(5)).ToString();


        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox6.Clear();
        textBox7.Clear();
        textBox8.Clear();
        textBox9.Clear();

        MessageBox.Show("Cambios registrados exitosamente");

        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        button1.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
        label13.Visible = false;
        label14.Visible = false;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución más al tuyo es:

1. Realiza tus cálculos en un método aparte para que lo puedas
   reutilizar en cualquier evento del DataGridView o en algún otro
   botón.

En este caso lo llamo **sumaColumas**.

```
public void sumaColumnas()
{
    var sumTotal1 = 0;
    var sumTotal2 = 0;
    var sumTotal3 = 0;
    //... mas variables

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        sumTotal1 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
        sumTotal2 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
        sumTotal3 += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
        //... más calculos
    }

    txtTotal1.Text = sumTotal1.ToString();
    txtTotal2.Text = sumTotal2.ToString();
    txtTotal3.Text = sumTotal3.ToString();
    //... más cajas de texto

    // ----
    txtDiv1.Text = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal1.Text) / 5;
    txtDiv2.Text = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal2.Text) / 5;
    txtDiv3.Text = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal3.Text) / 5;
    //... Mas divisiones
}
```

y cuando insertas nuevas filas con tu botón **insertar** solo mandas a llamar el método y actualizará tus campos de texto con los nuevos cálculos.

ejemplo.

```
private void btnInsertar_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // … tu código de configuración de columnas, etc

    // agregas una nueva columna
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtVal1.Text, txtVal2.Text, txtVal3.Text);

    // Llamas el método sumar(al ultimo para que tome los nuevos valores agregados)
    sumaColumnas();
}
```

En DatagridView tiene un comportamiento como las de Excel, al modificar una celda lo que haces es dar doble clic en una celda y aparece el cursor para modificar el valor, remplazas el valor y con un enter validas la modificación, lo mismo se puede realizar en este caso y para que detecte al cambio en una celda de dataGridView existe un evento del mismo llamado **CellEndEdit** y dentro de ese mandas a llamar el método creado y éste hará los cálculos tomando el nuevo valor.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    sumaColumnas();
}
```

Como comenté desde el principio es una idea más a tu solución, de eso se trata este mundo, varias soluciones a un problema...Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo SSV ITT, no sabia que en c# existiera una función similar a la de excel, no cabe duda que cada día se aprende mas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

lo mejor que puedes hacer es en lugar de llamar a la función que calcula los valores de los `TextBox` en los eventos de los botones, lo suyo seria realizar el calculo y  modificar los `TextBox` en el evento `RowValidated` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

En el diseñador añades el evento del datagrid de esta forma:

```
 this.dataGridView1.RowValidated += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgv_RowValidating);
```

Y en dicho evento realizas los cálculos que antes estabas realizando en los eventos de los botones:

```
private void dgv_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Aquí iría el código que calcula los valores por columnas y los añade a los textbox

}
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: Buen día ElGerar, muy bien excelente si sirvo de la forma que me recomendaste, mi punto de vista es que para el usuario que maneja el sistema es mas fácil y comodo presionar un botón, entonces mi pregunta es: ¿se puede meter la activación de ese evento dentro de un botón?